# How to send Print command direct to Printer by webpage without popup on client side

Tags: asp.net, printing

I am trying to print some reports in .Net website where I am trying to start print directly without any preview on client machine and without any popup from my website.
Any code or 3rd party plugin (Paid/Free)?

Comment: Thank god such a plugin or code does not exist. What do you think would happen if websites could print documents without user interaction. Spam per printer, sound like fun...